# How to use .format() on input from .getstr() in Python 3 curses?

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-3.5, curses

I'm trying to learn some very basic use of the curses library in Python 3.5.

I'm facing the following problem: after retrieving the string "foo" with `.getstr()`, if I use the string method `.format()` what is printed is the string with a prefixed b and apostrophes: `b'foo'` instead of just `foo`.
Does .getstr return something different than a common string?

What is happening here? What should I do to have just the variable printed?

Here few lines of code to show the issue:

```
import curses


def main(scr):
    scr.clear()
    curses.echo()
    scr.addstr(0, 0, "Write...")
    a = scr.getstr(1, 0)
    scr.addstr(
        2, 0, "You wrote...\nWith string.format:"
        "\n{}\nCalling directly the variable:\n".format(a))
    scr.addstr(6, 0, a)
    scr.addstr(8, 0, "Press Return to quit")
    scr.getkey()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From `getstr` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getstr)
:

> Read a bytes object from the user, with primitive line editing capacity.

So this API returns a `bytes` object that represents, well, raw data. You can convert it to text using `a.decode()` (it will assume UTF-8 encoding by default).

Literature:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html